# Can classes be referenced outside App_Code?

Tags: asp.net

I know this seems pretty basic, but I've been working with MVC for awhile and I'm not sure what works with asp.net.

Is it possible to organize code outside the App_Code directory or into separate projects? How would this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You have a couple choices.  One is to use Web Application Projects instead of Web Site projects.  WAP's have a LOT more control over where code lives, compilation, etc.

Another is to create a Class Library project and reference this from your existing project.  This is a great way to share code amongst multiple projects and/or solutions.

Incidentally, if you are wanting to stick with MVC, then I'd highly suggest you investigate [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).  I've heard nothing but good things about it.  Personally, I'm not 100% sold on MVC; but the people I know who are love Razor.

Comment: I use mvc and razor on my current site and it rocks :) The problem is this is a company website and it's stuck in the .net 1.1 era... I would love to use a WAP, but the site doesn't compile so I have to run it as a website and just make changes to individual files :(

Comment: In that case it has to be a separate class library. See @Joel Coehoorn's answer

Comment: @chobo: as a side note, if you really want to upgrade that 1.1 site you could post a new question with the conversion issues you are faced with during the upgrade...

Answer (score 2):

To move code outside of the App_Code folder, you need to place it in a separate class library project, and the dll output from that project must registered in the GAC on your web server (and each of your development machines).

It's this last part that annoys me most, as it's not easy getting all the working with a source control system where the relevant revision that you need installed in the GAC on your local machine may change frequently.

Comment: I haven't worked with web site projects in Years.  Do you really have to GAC an assembly for the project to reference it or is it just good enough to have it referenced by the WAP and placed in it's bin directory?

Comment: @chobo: Global Assembly Cache.  It's MS's replacement for putting everything into /windows/system32

Comment: @Chris - bin folder can work, but if this code is shared among several related applications that quickly becomes a nightmare to keep up with.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, when you have a separate class library project, it doesn't have to reside in the GAC all the time.  If you don't want to deal with the GAC, just set the project reference to that library and set the "Copy Local" property of that reference to True (this is a default behavior) and its done.  When you compile your web site it automatically includes the .dll for that library in your BIN folder.  But if you have multiple project referencing the same library then it makes sense to have it in GAC rather than having it in the BIN folder.  Those are my 2 cents... :)